# How to add/retrieve the post trash link?

Tags: nonce, trash

I am creating a plugin to display all posts from all custom post type. It is something like in `edit.php`, but instead of displaying single post type, I would like to display all posts in one page from multiple custom post type.

I follow the tutorial at [here](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) to create the plugin and I did it. However there is one problem now, I want to add the trash link under every listed posts (just like in `edit.php`). This field requires a nonce in order to run, but I couldn't get it how it works.

Here is my codes:

```
function column_post_title($item){
$actions = array(
        'edit' => sprintf('<a href="'.admin_url('post.php?post=%s&action=edit').'">Edit</a>',$item['ID']),//this part is fine
        'trash'=> sprintf('<a href="'.wp_nonce_url(admin_url().'post.php?post=%s&action=trash', 'trash-%s').'">Trash</a>',$item['ID'],$item['ID']),//here I cant get it right!!
    );
return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['post_title'], $this->row_actions($actions) );
}
```

Do I need to create own nonce? Or using the exist one (if there is any). From the code above it give me WordPress failure notice with:

> Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `get_delete_post_link( $post_ID )` - it'll return the absolute URL with nonce and all!

**Just to be clear**, this will get the link to **trash** posts (if trash supported). If you want to skip trash & get the perma-delete link<strike>, pass a second argument of `true`</strike>*.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_delete_post_link

**Update:** Having checked the source, it seems the codex is a little out of date. The second argument is deprecated, so pass an empty string & the *third* arg as `true`:

```
get_delete_post_link( $post_ID, '', true );
```

Comment: But I don't want delete, I just want to move the posts to trash.

Comment: @tc.k - you've to `echo` the first code `get_delete_post_link( $post_ID )` to only trash it. the second one will permanently delete that post

Comment: Okay..i tested it...it works!!!thank you very much!!!